# why when i gave maring auto, my buttons displays under each other

Tags: html, css

I have some buttons,i gave them margin auto and display:block. when i run it, margin auto runs correctly but buttons show under each other . can some one help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: of course,i gave this styles for my  buttons:                                                                                                            border: 1px solid black;
    background:white;
    font-size: 16px;
    display:table;
    margin:0px auto;
    margin-top: 2px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the buttons centered but next to each other, wrap them in a div and put margin:auto on the wrapping div.

Comment: Sure, don't forget to accept my answer and upvote it.